# What's the formula to compute the divided difference approximation for the third order greeks?

Tags: options, greeks

I can't seem to find the quotient required to approximate the third order greeks 
Speed, Zomma, Color and Ultima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first order accuracy you can use:

$f^3(x)=\frac{1}{h^3}\left(f(x+2h)-3f(x+h)+3f(x)-f(x-h) \right)$

For the second order accuracy:

$f^3(x)=\frac{1}{2h^3}\left(f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+2f(x-h)-f(x-2h) \right)$

Comment: See discussion here as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301769/approximation-formula-for-third-derivative-is-my-approach-right